# How to access to differents methods of webservice with SOAPUI

Tags: c#, asp.net, soapui

I try to access to my webmethods with SOAP UI but it works only for the first one and I don't undestand why.

My Webservices methods :

```
[SoapHeader ("AuthenticationInfo", Required=true)]
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {

        if (!(AuthenticationInfo.Username == "test" && AuthenticationInfo.Password == "test"))
        {               
            throw new Exception();
            // I put that in the aim to get an error, I'll modify this  later
        }

        return "OK";

    }

    [SoapHeader("AuthenticationInfo", Required = true)]
    [WebMethod]
    public string Authenticate(string MethodName)
    {
        if (!(AuthenticationInfo.Username == "test" && AuthenticationInfo.Password == "test")
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else
        {
            HelloWorld();
        }
        return "aaaa";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public int Calcul(int a, int b)
    {           
        return a+b ;
    }
```

When I put this XML in SOAP UI :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Username>test</Username>
      <Password>test</Password>
      <key>string</key>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope
```

It works perfectly, I get the return of HelloWord() Method.
But if I put :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Calcul xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <a>1</a>
      <b>1</b>
    </Calcul>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It invokes again HelloWorld() method. My URL which I use in SOAP UI is :"http://localhost:62353/MyWebService.asmx", so I try a new request with the last XML at the URL "http://localhost:62353/MyWebService.asmx/Calcul" and i have an error.

Have you I Idea ? May I'm in the wrong way to use SOAP UI ?

To reply to Kosala W : 
I get an UI like that where I can click on the methods. The calcul methods works only here because this methos doesn't need the SoapHeader.

[image]

Comment: When you run your web service project in browser, what are the methods that you can see? Can you click on them and see the schema?

Comment: @KosalaW I put an image of the screen when i run the web service project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the response :

When you specify the URL in SOAP UI you need to add ?wsdl at the end like that : `http://localhost:62353/MyWebService.asmx?wsdl` Then I refresh the project in SOAP UI and all the methods appears